# Mouse Scroll Normalisation + Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouse, normalize

I'm currently in the process of producing a website. This website features an element that horizontally scrolls through a carousel of images. This acts as the client's portfolio.

In an attempt to improve the user experience, I included the following script (in conjuction with [jquery.mousewheel.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/blob/master/jquery.mousewheel.js)) to translate any vertical mouse scrolling to horizontal scrolling when hovering over the `.carousel` element.

```
$('.carousel').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {

  $(this).scrollLeft(this.scrollLeft + (-delta * 40));

  e.preventDefault();

});
```

This works fine in translating the input.

The problem I'm facing is that different input devices (Trackpad, Regular Mouse) scroll at vastly different rates, despite [jquery.mousewheel.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/blob/master/jquery.mousewheel.js) handling normalisation between these devices.

If I adjust the script to allow for trackpads (`-delta * 1`), the regular mouse will scroll way to slowly (around one pixel per wheel adjustment). If I allow for regular mouse input (`-delta * 40`), trackpads will scroll ridiculously fast.

[Here is an example of the intended functionality.](http://www.jarradseng.com/)

The only things I can think of, is that the second script is in some way interfering with [jquery.mousewheel.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/blob/master/jquery.mousewheel.js), perhaps preventing the normalisation initialising correctly. Secondly, and more likely, I'm not implementing this correctly.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: think about maybe throttling the function? Alternatively make the number dynamic and not a constant, changing by the amount of triggers per second.

Comment: @Dellirium If I understand correctly, throttling will (in this context) restrict the maximum speed of the scroll? Is this correct?

Comment: Throttling restricts the number of times a function will fire, which will not restrict the speed but will restrict the number of times you move your scroll per restriction time. That is to say, you'd for example only ever be able to scroll 10 iterations per 1 second, if you setup your throttle that way. I am not sure if this would be satisfactory though, since it might feel spiky. Better choice would be to dynamically reduce the number `40` towards `1` faster and faster as more triggers of this function occur

Comment: @Dellirium I was under the impression that the above mentioned [jquery.mousewheel.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/blob/master/jquery.mousewheel.js) already does this.

Comment: @Dellirium Here is an excerpt from their README: _"The combination of Browsers, Operating Systems, and Devices offer a huge range of possible delta values. In fact if the user uses a trackpad and then a physical mouse wheel the delta values can differ wildly. This plugin normalizes those values so you get a whole number starting at +-1 and going up in increments of +-1 according to the force or acceleration that is used."_

Comment: Can you console log the delta on track pad and mouse and tell us the values you get, do a few tests since all that is needed is a rough estimate

Comment: @Dellirium My understanding of JS is rather limited. How am I to do that? `console.log(wheelDelta)`?

Comment: Okay, got it. But the values change depending how fast I scroll? I got values of anywhere between 407 and 1. Edit: Just got a value of 589. @Dellirium

Comment: even with the mousewheel? The values are suppose to change, that is what `mousewheel.js` does. However there should be a descrepency between what you get on a mouse versus what you get with a trackpad, or can you get low values even with the trackpad?

Comment: What you presented in your initial question is that if you multiply the value by `40`, your mousewheel works normally (meaning mousewheel delta is probably small) meanwhile if you use a trackpad, and value is `40`, it scrolls instantly, meaning trackpad should present high delta values. With value low as `1` your mouse is very slow while trackpad is normal. This means that the delta given by trackpad should be vastly higher then that given by a mouse. If that is the case we need to conclude what the difference is, at least a rough estimate

Comment: @Dellirium Regular mouse wheel is a 3. Apologies, the values I referenced above were for Apple Mouse/Trackpad.

Comment: Alright so there are multiple ways to solve this, I mean one of them being to simply not use the delta and just have it scroll at same speeds, and alternative being to normalize the delta values yourself. Formula such as square root is a good normalization tool. You probably want something like `Math.sqrt(delta) * 20` and use that as a value.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll give it a go and check back in. I'm essentially swapping out the `(-delta * 40)` for your above example, correct?

Comment: Yes, because if your delta varies between 1 and 600 that is a huge variance, by using `sqrt` you reduce that to a range of 1 - 25.  Then you can work with that number and pixels and whatnot. You could (I would) even do double sqrt, then multiply it  by like 30 or even 40, for even more normalization, but that might defeat the sensitivity too much and then might as well just put a constant. Across the spectrum neutral formula would be somewhat like (Math.sqrt(delta) * 20 + 85)) from what i estimate

Comment: Lower that 85 for less sensitivity and increase it for more